# Make ng-model that's not automatically updating the value

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have an `<input>`, showing a number. I used `ng-model` to bind this number to a variable. My problem is that I don't want the variable to change simply on input, I want it to change on button click, but I also want a default value shown in the input to be the one that's stored in the variable.

To make it slightly clearer:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="foo">
<button ng-click="updateFoo()">Update foo</button>
{{foo}}
```

I want `foo` to reflect changes only when button is pressed, but if I refresh the page, `{{foo}}` will show some value (logic to retrieve the values exist).

The way I currently did it, in my AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.foo = 5;

$scope.updateFoo = function(num){
  $scope.foo = num;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="not_in_controller">
<button ng-click="updateFoo(not_in_controller)">Update foo</button>
{{foo}}
```

This works as I want it to, but the input is empty by default.

Another thought was to use two variables, one is for presentation, another one is set after clicking the button

Comment: You are already using 2 variables; to initialize, just add `$scope.not_in_controller = $scope.foo;` in your controller (and choose a better name for `not_in_controller`).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `ng-init` directive:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="not_in_controller" ng-init="not_in_controller=5">
<button ng-click="updateFoo(not_in_controller)">Update foo</button>
{{not_in_controller}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `value="{{ foo }}"` in your `<input />`

Here a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5s3cjyuw/